Probability distribution function for boundaries on brownian motion
What would be the probability distribution function for Brownian motion with two boundaries, i.e. a stop loss and take profit. The process is a standard Brownian motion. However at values $a$ and $b$ any random walk past these points is stopped. What would be the distribution for this function.

Assume that the standard Brownian motion $W$ starts at $0$, and that $a<0<b$. Let $\tau$ be the first hitting time of $W$ at $a$ or $b$. By Wald's identity, $0=\mathbb E W_\tau = b\mathbb P[W_\tau=b] + a(1-\mathbb P[W_\tau=b])$, so
$$P[W_\tau=b] = \frac{-a}{b-a}.$$
And so
$$P[W_\tau=a] = 1-\mathbb P[W_\tau=b] = \frac{b}{b-a}.$$
